# ¿Por qué no me deja usar el metodo .append?

Tags: python, lista

Estoy iniciando con Python. Resulta que quiero hacer un código en el que se "lancen dos dados" y repetir un número determinado de veces el proceso y guardar los resultados en una lista, pero no me deja usar el método `.append`, ni siquiera me aparece en las predicciones del código.

Estaba queriendo hacer algo así:

```
import random 
combinaciones: []

for i in range (20):
  dado1= random.randint(1,6)
  dado2= random.randint(1,6)
  combinaciones.append(dado1+dado2)

print(combinaciones)
```

Por favor, alguien me dice ¿qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Probaste cambiar el : por = en la segunda linea?

Comment: En Python, el : tiene un significado distinto al =.

Comment: Tienen razón, Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola Herman en el código que publicas noto y comprobé que efectivamente el problema  esta en : y efectuando un cambio por el signo = tendrás el resultado que deseas.

Comment: Esto perece más un comentario que una respuesta

Comment: Ah si, ahí pude. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score -3):

El siguiente código es la corrección de la pregunta

import random
Combinar=[]

```
for i in range (20):
    dado1= random.randint(1,6)

    dado2= random.randint(1,6)

    Combinar.append(dado1 + dado2)

print(Combinar)
```

Comment: En lugar de agregar una nueva respuesta, edita la anterior, ya que es más un comentario que una respuesta. Además, _¿qué hace este código?_ Lee [answer].